# Cardinality of a set of points

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to calculate the cardinality of the following set

$$A = \{ (a/k, b/(nk)) : 0 \le a < k, 0 \le b < nk \}$$

I can (kind of) visualise it as a grid of isolated points, so I think it has cardinality $(k-1)(nk-1)$, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your $j$ is clearly supposed to be $b$. Your answer is almost right: you do indeed have a rectangular grid of points, but it there are $k$ possibilities for $a$, not $k-1$, and $nk$ for $b$, not $nk-1$, because you’re including $0$ as a possibility in both cases.